# What are the hardware dependencies for a compass application to work on an android phone?

Tags: android

I have Samsung Galaxy Trend Lite S7392 phone.
I have downloaded and installed a compass application. What are the
sensors that are required for the compass application to work on the phone?

Answer (score -1):

Most Android Devices have a `Geomagnetic Field Sensor` built in. This sensor provides raw field strength data (in μT) for each of the three coordinate axes.